# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable issue

Tags: python

I've been looking through the internet and as many others before, can't find the answer I keep on getting the **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable** bug every time I try to run my program which is meant to ask a question for the user to answer then add up their score, I need to fix this if I want to continue

```
input = ("What is your name?")
print = ("I will ask you 10 questions and give you three choices for each question \n IMPORTANT! PLEASE KEEP YOUR CAPSLOCK ON")

score = 0
score = int(score)

q1 = input("What piece of code would show a word/sentence and nothing else \n A. print () \n B. input () \n C. int(print) ")

if q1 == ("A") :
    print ("Well done! That is correct")
    score = score + 1
    print ("Your score is",score,)
elif q1 == ("B") :
    print ("That is incorrect")
elif q1 == ("C") :
    print ("That is incorrect")
```

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: You've overwritten the `print` function with a string. Use a different variable name

Comment: @Farhan.K I suspect OP didn't mean to assign to that name at all, they meant to actually call `print()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah that's probably the case. @Pegaferno You'll want to get rid of the `=` after `print` in that case

Answer (score 5):

```
input = ("What is your name?")
print = ("I will ask you 10 questions and give you three choices for each question \n IMPORTANT! PLEASE KEEP YOUR CAPSLOCK ON")
```

overwrites the `input` and `print` functions, with strings. Use

```
name = input("What is your name?") # the input will be stored in name
print("""I will ask you 10 questions and give you three choices for each question.
IMPORTANT! PLEASE KEEP YOUR CAPSLOCK ON.""")
```